# elasticsearch regex pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

can anyone help me match results by words in elasticsearch regex? I am new to regex.

If I have strings as per below :

- string 1: *"Hello, are you fine?"*
- string 2: *"Does she use youtube?"*

If I search for *"you"* word in elastic search then I want just *"string 1"* as an output. and If I search for *"are you"* then it should also give me a *"string 1"* as an output.

I tried with below regex but not giving me the expected output :

- pattern 1: `".*you.*"` - it's giving me both string as an output.
- pattern 2: `"/\syou\s/"` - it's not giving me an nay output.

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: Did you try with `/\byou\b/` ?

Comment: @EricLavault I tried with /\byou\b/ but it's not working. :(

Comment: Please post your full search query. Are the quotation marks actually part of your strings and/or search patterns?

Comment: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'https://elastic:d0vEW5M90ItbwHuX9ttNo0ig@9fe010fe485944eca402f7104ff565bc.us-west-1.aws.found.io:9243/products_master/_search?pretty&scroll=10m&size=10' -d '{ "query": { "bool": { "must": [{ "bool": { "should": [ {"regexp": {"name": "/\bbeds\b/"}}, {"regexp": {"brand_data.brand_name": "/\bbeds\b/"}}, {"regexp": {"model_number": "/\bbeds\b/"}}, {"regexp": {"Categories": "/\bbeds\b/"}} ] } } ] } }, "aggs": { "products-by-brand": { "terms": { "field": "brand_id", "size": 500 } } } }
'

Comment: Lucene has no `\b` support

Comment: so, what can I use for word search? can anyone tell me